# Calling the Java compiler from a Common Lisp application, on Java source created by the Lisp application

Tags: java, lisp, common-lisp

I've written an application in Common Lisp which produces Java source code and writes it to a *.java file.

I would like to finish off the Lisp code with a call to the Java compiler, and finally to run the compiled Java code.

**All from within the Lisp application.**

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_compiler

Answer (score 3):

You might want to run the Java compiler as an external process. All modern Common Lisp implementations sheep with ASDF, which includes its UIOP library (Utilities for Implementation- and OS- Portability).

So, straight off, try this:

```
(uiop:run-program (list "javac" "--option" "myfile.java") :output t)
```

The `:output t` makes it print to standard output.

From within lisp, an error will bring the interactive debugger pop up. If you want to catch and print errors nicely:

```
(handler-case 
          (uiop:run-program (list "javac" "--stuff") :output t)
        (error (c) (format t "~a" c)))
```

To run it asynchronously, use `launch-program`.

Read more: https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/os.html#running-external-programs

Answer (score 2):

There is no language-defined way to invoke external programs from CL.  However many implementations provide a way to do this, and there is a compatibility library called [external-program](https://github.com/sellout/external-program) which provides a common wrapper to this functionality for many implementations.

This library itself is available via [Quicklisp](https://www.quicklisp.org/beta/).

Comment: Also available are `uiop:run-program` and `uiop:launch-program`, which is part of ASDF and thus _already there_ almost everywhere.